# Giving write permission to a directory linux

Tags: php, file-permissions, netbeans, fedora-14

I have a strange problem. I gave a directory `ci` with `chmod 777 ci` permission. The `ls -l` command shows

```
drwxrwxrwx. 5 root root 4096 Jan 1 18:08 ci
```

But when I tried to create a file `innetbeans`, it shows *The target folder is read-only*. What is wrong?

Comment: Is the mount point where the directory is located mounted as read-only?

Comment: It is in root directory..`/var/www/html`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a server problem. This is happening because your directory needs server permission to write.
Try this as root user:

```
chmod 7777 -R ci
```

(here 4th 7 is for server permission )

Comment: What do you mean by "server permission"?

Comment: Actually I'm not sure it's related to the actual problem or not.  It's like whenever file or directory is created on server by remote client than you need server permission to create those file for remote client.